# How do I create a layout module for angular in a feature-based pattern

Tags: angularjs, webpack

Assuming that my angular file structure follows modularized structure rather than the standard one (views, controllers, etc.), I am having some pain to find a standard way to make a main container whose partials such as navigation or header will be shared by other features other than home.

I import every feature through webpack(index.js) and because of that there exist different routing files.

To sum up, I'm trying to add main layout to [this example](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/)